# display function for nested singly linked list c

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Im writing database program for my c class for few days now im trying to figure out how to work with singly linked lists its pretty hard to understand I would say ,well at least for me. Overall I got part of code necessary for my project, basicaly I got functions to add client and items to client thanks to help of somebody from stackoverflow I kinda figured how to add multiple items to 1 client but now I'm in trouble figuring out how exactly can I print it ,tried to do it the way you can see im my display function but it doesnt work for items linked to client what should I change to make it work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct item{
char item_name[30];
struct item *NextItem;
};
struct client{
    struct client *NextClient;
    char name[30];
    char last_name[30];
    struct item *firstItem;
  struct item *lastItem;
};
struct client *head = NULL;
/////////////////////////////
struct client* FindTailClient(struct client* head)
{
    struct client *temp = head;
    while( temp->NextClient != NULL)
    {

       temp = temp->NextClient;
    }
    return temp;
}
/////////////////////////////
////////
 struct client *GetClientData()
  {
      char data[30];
    struct client *temp;
    temp = (struct client*)malloc(sizeof(struct client));

    printf("Enter the person's name--->");
    scanf("%s",data);
    strcpy(temp->name,data);
    printf("Enter the person's last name--->");
    scanf("%s",data);
    strcpy(temp->last_name,data);
    temp->NextClient = NULL;
    return temp;
  }
///////////
struct item *GetItemData()
  {
    struct item *temp;
    char data[30];
    temp = (struct item*)malloc(sizeof(struct item));

    printf("Enter the item name--->");
    scanf("%s",data);
    strcpy(temp->item_name,data);
    temp->NextItem = NULL;
    return temp;
  }
///////////
//////////////
struct client* AddClient()
{
  struct client *temp,temp1;
  temp=head;
  struct client *data = GetClientData();



  if(head == NULL)
  {
      head=data;
      head->NextClient = NULL;
  }
  else
  {
     while(temp->NextClient != NULL)
     {
     temp=temp->NextClient;
     }
     data->NextClient=NULL;
     temp->NextClient=data;
  }
}
///////////////////

///////////////////

///////////////////
void display()
{
    struct client *CurrentClient = head;
struct item *ItemCurrent = head->firstItem;
      while(CurrentClient != NULL)
      {
        printf(" -> %s ->%s \n",CurrentClient->name,CurrentClient->last_name);
               while(ItemCurrent != NULL)
               {
               printf(" -> %s\n",ItemCurrent->item_name);
               ItemCurrent=ItemCurrent->NextItem;
               }
      CurrentClient=CurrentClient->NextClient;
      }

}
///////////////////
void AddItemToClient(struct client* head, struct item *item)
{
    item->NextItem = NULL;
    if(head->firstItem == NULL) {
        head->firstItem = item;
    } else {
        head->lastItem->NextItem = item;
    }
    head->lastItem = item;

}
///////////////////
struct client *find(struct client *head, char name[])
{
    while (head->NextClient != NULL )
    {
        if (strcmp(head->name,name) == 0)
        {
            printf("Target found: %s\n",head->name);
            return head;
        }
        head = head->NextClient;
    }
    printf("target not found");
    return NULL;
}
//////////////////
int main()
{
    int i;
    char data[30];
    char name[30];
    struct client *temp;
    struct client *head;
    struct item *data1;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
    AddClient();
    }
    printf("Insert name to find:");
    scanf("%s",name);
temp = find(&head,name);
data1 = GetItemData();
AddItemToClient(temp,&data1);
display();
}
```

Comment: 1. Fix AddClient to actually fulfill the return value promise its declaration claims. 2. You're passing a pointer-to-pointer (i.e. the address of a pointer) to `find()` (and is broken regardless), which expects just a pointer. The same is true for `AddItemToClient(temp,&data1)`. Crank up the warnings on your compiler.

Comment: well in code blocks it compiles without any warning :|

Comment: So basicaly if I'm correct I have to delete & from those 2 lines:   temp = find(&head,name);
AddItemToClient(temp,&data1);
as when i tried to compile in dev i had warnings for those, and when I deleted those had no warning was compiling but function to find didnt work at all after I did it but with those it worked fine. Pointers confuse me so badly.. :|

Comment: at display : `struct item *ItemCurrent = head->firstItem;` It is necessary to set the CurrentClient each.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "It is necessary to set CurrentClient each possibly in more detailed way? :x

Answer (score 0):

In this line: "while(ItemCurrent != ItemLast)" - ItemLast is undeclared. Maybe you wanted to write head->lastItem, or better ItemCurrent->next != NULL.
Also, make sure you store the clients you just created to be able to access them: head = AddClient(); instead of simply AddClient();

Comment: forgot to change it before posting as was trying to figure it out , it was supposed to be ItemCurrent != NULL in my code